# How to prove the Nginx smoothing weight load balancing algorithm mathematically?

Tags: java, algorithm, nginx, math

Refer to a code submission by Nginx : https://github.com/phusion/nginx/commit/27e94984486058d73157038f7950a0a36ecc6e35

```
class Server {
    String name;
    int weight;
    int curWeight;

    Server(String name, int weight) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    void add(int weight) {
        curWeight += weight;
    }

    void subtract(int weight) {
        curWeight -= weight;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s=%2d", name, curWeight);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public int getCurWeight() {
        return curWeight;
    }

}

class LoadBalance {
    private int matched = -1;
    private Server[] servers;

    LoadBalance(Server... servers) {
        super();
        this.servers = servers;
    }

    Server get() {
        int totalWeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0, len = servers.length; i < len; i++) {
            servers[i].add(servers[i].getWeight());
            totalWeight += servers[i].getCurWeight();
            if (matched == -1 || servers[matched].getCurWeight() < servers[i].getCurWeight()) {
                matched = i;
            }
         }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(servers) + " " + servers[matched].getName() + " selected");
        servers[matched].subtract(totalWeight);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(servers));

        return servers[matched];
    }

}

public class LoadBalanceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LoadBalance loadBalance = new LoadBalance(new Server("a", 5), new Server("b", 1), new Server("c", 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            loadBalance.get();
        }
    }

}
```

When input node (a, b, c) has a weight ratio of (5,1,1), the output result is as follows :

```
[a= 5, b= 1, c= 1] a selected
[a=-2, b= 1, c= 1]
[a= 3, b= 2, c= 2] a selected
[a=-4, b= 2, c= 2]
[a= 1, b= 3, c= 3] b selected
[a= 1, b=-4, c= 3]
[a= 6, b=-3, c= 4] a selected
[a=-1, b=-3, c= 4]
[a= 4, b=-2, c= 5] c selected
[a= 4, b=-2, c=-2]
[a= 9, b=-1, c=-1] a selected
[a= 2, b=-1, c=-1]
[a= 7, b= 0, c= 0] a selected
[a= 0, b= 0, c= 0]
[a= 5, b= 1, c= 1] a selected
[a=-2, b= 1, c= 1]
[a= 3, b= 2, c= 2] a selected
[a=-4, b= 2, c= 2]
[a= 1, b= 3, c= 3] b selected
[a= 1, b=-4, c= 3]
```

For each 7 executions (weight sum), the weight is reset to 0, and the proportion of service allocation times also satisfies the weight proportion, and the distribution is also relatively uniform a, a, b, a, c, a and a.

But I don't understand why that is.How to prove the algorithm mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly clear what exactly is the property you want to be proven. The correctness with regarding to weights is not hard to prove.

Assume we have integer weights `Wi` with sum `S`.

**Claim #1:** over `S` consecutive selections each `i`-th server will be selected exactly `Wi` times.

Here is a sketch of the proof. Claim #1 follows from the **Claim #2:** at no point server with a negative current weight (`CWi`) can be selected. Which in turn follows from the **Claim #3**: at every step the sum of all current weights is 0.

The Claim #3 is obviously true: at each step of the algorithm we add each `Wi` to the current weights `CWi` and subtract `S` from the one being selected. So we add and subtract `S`. So the sum stays the same as it was before the first step i.e. 0.

If the sum is always 0, it means that if there is some negative current weight, there must be a positive current weight. Obviously any positive current weight is a better choice than a negative one so we have the Claim #2 proven.

Back to the Claim #1: Assume some `i`-th sever has been selected `Ni` times, more then `Wi`. Let's look at the last time such a selection was made. Let that be some step number `j` (`0 < j < S`, strictly speaking you need to also consider the case of the selection at the very first step `j=0`, but it is obvious that every server with non-zero weight will be selected at least once so "overflow" can't happen at the first step). At `j`-th step its current weight `CWi = j*Wi - (Ni-1)*S`. Since `Ni > Wi`, it means `Ni-1 >= Wi`; and `j < S`. So `j*Wi < (Ni-1)*S` or `CWi < 0`. And we know that a server with a negative current weight can never be selected. Contradiction.

Now assume some `i`-th server has been selected less times then `Wi`. Since the total number of server selections is fixed, some other `j`-the server has been selected more times than `Wj` and we already know that can't happen. This finishes our proof for the Claim #1.

As for "*the distribution is also relatively uniform*" part it is not a formalized statement and thus can't be proven.